# Why can't I store a number in a list and use that number to lead to a "choice"?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, if-statement

So this is one of my first ever (by myself) programs i've created.
I'm stuck on a certain part though, not going to list the whole script, just the part i'm stuck on.:

```
import random
roll_dice = random.randint(0,11)
Player_Number = []

def char_creation():
    ROLL = ("YOU ROLLED A %d !" % roll_dice)
    Player_Number.append(ROLL)


def player_choices(char_creation):
    if Player_Number == 0:
        print ("Your character is Super Man!")
    elif Player_Number == 1:
        print ("Your character is Bat Man!")

    (Not going to continue listing choices)



char_creation()
player_choices(char_creation)
```

Basically this is what i'm having problems with. And understanding. I can't roll a random number, store it in a list, and have the number choose a choice based on that number? Sorry, i'm really new to programming. Any tips would be appreciated!

EDIT: Actually another problem came to mind as I was reading this over:

```
class character_(object):
    def __init__(self, name, health, moral):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.moral = moral

class Super_Man(object):
    def __init__(self, name="Super Man", health=200, moral=25):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.moral = moral
        print (" {0} is your character! ".format(self.name))
```

So i'm just confused. If I want to have seperate classes (characters with specific attribute amounts), do I even have to create the first class I made?
Or can I just make separate classes based on the character/character's attributes?
How would this effect if I wanted to subtract or add Health/Moral based on decisions?

Comment: You can't compare a list to a number as you're doing, but you can compare one of its elements to a number. But it isn't clear what the purpose of the list is here.

Comment: The purpose of the list, is for a random number to be chosen, then stored in a list. Using that number, it will decide which character the player will be given.. So you can use len(Player_Number), but not specifically compare that number and use it for a decision?

Comment: What isn't clear is why you need a list at all instead of just storing the number in a variable.

Comment: Because i'm a noob, and that's a great IDEA :D :D :D :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would do for the second part is create superman as a character object. You've defined character objects to have a name, health and morale. You then use that template to create a superman object.

ie

```
SuperMan = character();

SuperMan.name = "Super Man"
SuperMan.health = 250
SuperMan.morale = 25
```

This would be how you would implement random character selection in Python.

```
import random
roll_dice = random.randint(0,2)

def player_choices(x):
    if Player_Number == 0:
        print ("Your character is Super Man!")
    else Player_Number == 1:
        print ("Your character is Bat Man!")

 player_choices(roll_dice)
```

I would suggest you view the documentation on Python class creation at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: How do I take the Player_Number and create the class instance? (In this case - Super Man). Create another function and do the if/elif/elif? if Player_Number == 0: SuperMan = Super_Man(self, name, health, moral)? Keeps telling me I'm not giving ENOUGH Arguments because of (self)? if I use name/health/moral, it says 3 arguments, 4 needed..

Comment: As far as why you can't store a player number, that's because the Player_Number declaration thinks Player_Number is a class or type, not the variable name. It should read something like Player_Number numbers = [];

Comment: You're right @interjay, I wasn't paying proper attention. The declaration is basically right but it is still taking the Player_Name as a class or type. Perhaps initializing it with an int value in brackets and then removing it would be more appropriate.